# Figure Margins to Large in Boxplot (with reproducible code)

Tags: r, error-handling, rstudio, boxplot

I have a data frame similar to the one below, and am trying to make a boxplot of it. But I get an error "Error in plot.new() : figure margins too large".

Been trying to trouble-shoot it reading other posts, but nothing has worked for my specific case. So, I am providing reproducible code. I would appreciate any of your help!!!

```
df = data.frame()
for (i in 1:760) {
  line = rbind(floor(runif(6, 1, 14701)))
  df = rbind(line, df)
}
boxplot(df, main = "Title", col = c("red", "orange", "green", "blue", "purple"), ylab = "Read count")
```

Comment: I'm assuming 'incr' is supposed to be 'df` for this example to run? But I don't get the same error you do. Make sure you close the plot window to reset any funny `par()` settings you may have set then run again.

Comment: I am using RStudio as well. How would I reset par() settings? How would I close the plot window? Sorry... I just want to make sure I do that correctly...

Comment: I don't run Rstudio so I can't say for sure. Usually there's a separate window for the drawing device output that you can close. Have you been changing `par()` settings? I mean, restarting Rstudio should reset everything but that is a bit dramatic.

Comment: No error for me using Rstudio. I would follow @MrFlick's advice.

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to reset some parameters using the command `dev.off()`, then try plotting again.  I ran the code provided, and received no errors.